# Using a FOR loop in JAVA to make 4 random numbers that together meet a certain condition

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

I am trying to have a randomly generated "Password" that can be verified by the fact that the 4 numbers in the sequence added together equal 21. I have already achieved my goal with a do-while loop. It looks like this:

```
int rand0;
int rand1;
int rand2;
int rand3;

do {
    rand0 = (int)(Math.random() * 10);
    rand1 = (int)(Math.random() * 10);
    rand2 = (int)(Math.random() * 10);
    rand3 = (int)(Math.random() * 10);
} while ((rand0 + rand1 + rand2 + rand3) != 21);

System.out.println(rand0 + "" + rand1 + "" + rand2 + "" + rand3);
```

But I am looking for a way to achieve the same thing using a FOR loop. I am not sure if it is possible. I have made some attempts, this is my latest though it obviously failed. Any insight would be greatly appreciated:

```
int pass1,
    pass2,
    pass3,
    pass4;

for ((String passWrd = pass1 + "" + pass2 + "" + pass3 + "" + pass4);
        ((pass1 + pass2 + pass3 + pass4) == 21);
        pass1 = (int) (Math.random() * 10)),
        (pass2 = (int) (Math.random() * 10)),
        (pass3 = (int) (Math.random() * 10)),
        (pass4 = (int) (Math.random() * 10))) {

    System.out.println(passWrd);
    break;
}
```

Comment: A `for` loop is used to do a certain thing a certain number of times. Why would you want to use it in this case? A `do...while` loop is the correct solution. Unless, that is, you're trying this as an exercise. In which case, the looping condition is wrong and should be `(pass1 + pass2 + pass3 + pass4) != 21`

Comment: [Java Code Conventions](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-contents.html) may be useful to you

Comment: I am indeed trying this as an exercise.

Comment: @Federico klez Culloca  is absolutely right, this requires a "do while" not a "for". You can learn much more by coming up with other more sound exercises

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca, see your point. and while I agree that a pointless exercise is pointless, I try to challenge what is possible based on what I know for the sake of some sort of deeper understanding, but I don't know enough yet to be able to decide for myself what isn't possible. So I will gladly take your advices and cancel this particular exercise.

Thanks.

Comment: Thank you @HoRn for those conventions. I will learn those.

Comment: @StoTheJB I think you meant to answer to dreamcrash :)

Comment: Yes, sorry, I also meant to answer to @dreamcrash

Comment: @StoTheJB I would not say that it is pointless because in the end it actually kind of teach you that the for loop is good for somethings and the do..while is good for others

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would rather generate the first 3 numbers randomly and calculate the 4th one so that it fulfills the condition of adding up to 21:

```
    Random random = new Random();
    int upperBound = 21;
    int value1 = random.nextInt(upperBound + 1);
    int value2 = random.nextInt(upperBound + 1 - value1);
    int value3 = random.nextInt(upperBound + 1 - value1 - value2);
    int value4 = upperBound - value1 - value2 - value3;
    int addition = value1 + value2 + value3 + value4;
    System.out.printf("Random numbers that add up %d: %d %d %d %d%n", addition, value1, value2, value3, value4);
```